# Как передать id элемента из цикла в другой блок приложение на framework7 js не хочет работать из за урла http://mobile.site.com/#!/author/incomming

Tags: php, javascript, framework7

Вот цикл:

```
<ul class="posts">
<?php foreach($letters_in as $item):?>
<?php $namePoet = $users->load($item['idfrom']);?>      
<li class="swipeout" style="display: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #e2dede;<?php if($item['letter_dateread'] == 0):?>background:#ececec;<?php endif;?>">
<div class="swipeout-content item-content">
<div class="post_entry">
<div class="post_date">
<span class="day"><?=date("d", $item['letter_datesend'])?></span>
<span class="month"><?=date("m.Y", $item['letter_datesend'])?></span>
</div>
<div class="post_title">
 <?php if($item['letter_dateread'] != 0):?>
 <div class="list_letter"><i class="fa fa-envelope-open-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
 <?php else:?>
 <div class="list_letter"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
 <?php endif;?>
 <h2><a href="author/inview?id=<?=$item['idletter'];?>"><?=getIconv($item['letter_title']);?></a></h2>
 <div class="letter_gif"><a href="author/info?id=<?=$namePoet->id;?>"><img src="/mobile/img/1.gif" alt="" title="" /><span><?=getIconv($namePoet->nick);?></span></a></div>
</div>
  <div class="post_swipe"><img src="/mobile/images/swipe_more.png" alt="" title="" /></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="swipeout-actions-right">
  <a href="author/inview?id=<?=$item['idletter'];?>" class="action1"><i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

  <a href="#" id="deleteletter" class="action1 open-popup" data-popup=".popup-social" class="open-popup"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 
  <div id=block></div>
 </div>
 </li> 
 <?php endforeach;?>
  </ul>

  <!-- DELETE -->
 <div class="popup popup-social">
  <div class="content-block">
  <h4>Видалення!</h4>
  <p>Ви впевнені в видаленні?</p> 
 <p class="buttons-row">  
  <a href="author/deletein?id=" class="button_full"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Видалення</a>
  <a href="#" class="button_full close-popup"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #fff;"></i>&nbsp;Відміна</a>
 </p>

 <div class="close_popup_button">
 <a href="#" class="close-popup" style="right: 40%;"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #fff;font-size: 70px;"></i>
 </a>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

нужно при нажатии на #deleteletter передать $item['idletter']; за цикл  Видалення

Comment: сделайте что-то с внешним видом примера...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите вам надо передать в скрипт показа модалки ID элемента для удаления, всё просто.

добавляем к примеру в открывашку data-attr

```
<a href="#" data-delete="author/inview?id=<?=$item['idletter'];?>" 
id="deleteletter" class="action1 open-popup" data-popup=".popup-social" 
class="open-popup"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

и в скрипте вызова модалки берём этот attr и запихиваем в href уже кнопки в модальном окне.

Более точно подсказать сложно, скриптов не приведено

Comment: Блин, я туплю напишите пример пожалуйста.

Comment: Сейчас попробую, на jaquery или native?

Comment: на jaquery , простой пример

Comment: Мне нужно при клике на линк: <a href="#" onclick="alert('<?=$item['idletter'];?>')" data-number="<?=$item['idletter'];?>" class="action1 open-popup"  data-popup=".popup-social" class="open-popup" id="123"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

Comment: передать id <?=$item['idletter'];?>

Comment: В модальное окно: <!-- DELETE -->
     <div id="applicationModal" class="popup popup-social">
      <div class="content-block">   
        <h4>Видалення! </h4>
        <p>Ви впевнені в видаленні?</p></div>
     </div>

Comment: Вот посмотрите https://jsfiddle.net/gussarah/5s6tmLm6/

Comment: Спасибо, я все понял буду пробовать.

Comment: там  атрибут не src а href $('.popup #modalDelete').attr('src', fullUrl);

Comment: ой, простите, запарился немного, спасибо за поправку

Comment: Спасибо Вам Большое